# Is it necessary to call `FD_SET` after the calling of `select` with a single FD?

Tags: c++, linux

```
//int fd <= socket fd
timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec  = 100;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

fd_set readfds;
FD_ZERO( &readfds );

FD_SET( fd, &readfds );
const int iRes = select( fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv );

if (iRes > 0)
{
    if (FD_ISSET( fd, &readfds )
    {
        // read from fd            
    }        
} else {
    // 0: timeout
    // -1: error in select
}
```

Question: Do I have to use `FD_ISSET` in above code before I can read from fd?
Based on my understanding, there is ONLY one fd in the read set and the return value is large than 0 then the passed in `fd` should be always in the `readfds`.

Comment: I thnk the answer should be obvious. If the FD is already set, you don't have to set it again.

Comment: But I think it would make the program more complicated if you only set the FD when it's really needed. You'll need to make it conditional on whether `select()` returned more than 0 versus returning because of an error or timeout. Why go to this trouble?

Comment: @Barmar, I will handle timeout case but here I just want to make sure my understanding is right. Based on example here, http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2933, the article always uses FD_ISSET.

Comment: Because he's showing the general case. In the usual case, you do need to call `FD_SET` every time, because there's usually more than one FD.

Comment: Basically, if the return value is the same as the number of FDs in the set, you don't need to call `FD_SET` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `FD_SET` if the return value of `select()` is the same as the total number of FD's that were set in all the input `fd_set`s. The case where you call it with just one `fd_set`, it only has one FD set, and `select` returns `1` is just a special case of this.